# Is there a collaborative anti-spam software for multiple clients sharing training data without server access except IMAP?

Tags: collaboration, email-client, spam

I'm using an email account together with other people (on different machines, locations and OS, currently all using Thunderbird >= 31.x). We only have control with IMAP, i.e. no sieve, no managesieve, no user accounts or other ways to execute something on the mail server. We're all moving spam to the same folder (by our convention) and training our client side spam filters. The efficiency of the spam filter training is `x/#{people accessing the account}` where `x` would be the efficiency of the training of the spam filter used by only one client. Is there a solution for us to automatically exchange and merge training data to get the efficiency of the training close to `x` (preferrably, but not necessarily with Thunderbird)?